# Prove that if $\langle Tx,x\rangle =0$ for all $x \in X$, then $T = 0$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

This is exercise 10 in section 3.2 of Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications:

> *(Zero Operator):* Let $T:X \to X$ be a bounded linear operator on complex inner product space $X$. If $\langle Tx,x\rangle =0$ for all $x \in X$, show that $T=0$.

I had solved little kindly guide me further

**Solution:**

Let $\langle Tx,x\rangle =0$ for all $x \in X$. Let $x=u+av$ where $v,u$ belong to $X$ and $a$ be the scalar then 
$$
\langle Tx,x\rangle =\langle T(u+av), u+av\rangle
$$
since $T$ is linear then 
\begin{align}
\langle Tx,x\rangle &=\langle Tu+aTv, u+av\rangle \\
    & =\langle Tu,u\rangle +\overline{a}\langle Tu,v\rangle +a\langle Tv,u\rangle +a\overline{a}\langle Tv,v\rangle \\
    & =\overline{a} \langle Tu,v\rangle +a\langle Tv,u\rangle 
\end{align}

Comment: I've made a quick edit to make your question readable.  In the future, please format your mathematical expressions using MathJax, as is described [on this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If $b(x,y)$ is a sesquilinear form (linear in the first coordinate, conjugate linear in the second) then $b(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}b(x+i^{n}y,x+i^{n}y)$. Apply this to $b(x,y)=\langle Tx,y\rangle$, knowing that $\langle Tx,x\rangle =0$.

Comment: How do you go from the 2nd line to the 3rd line when calculating $\langle Tx,x\rangle$?

Comment: @James Using that, on a *complex* inner product space, the inner product is conjugate-linear in the first variable and linear in the second by definition.

Answer (score 17):

**Hint:** The fact that $X$ is a **complex** inner product space is significant; this fails to hold for real inner product spaces.

You've done well to consider $\langle T(u + av), (u + av) \rangle$.  Now, note the following: since your equality is true for all $a$, it is true for any *single* value of $a$.  In particular, we have

- $\langle Tu,v \rangle + \langle Tv,u \rangle = 0$ (set $a = 1$)
- $\langle Tu,v \rangle - \langle Tv,u \rangle = 0$ (set $a = i$)

Comment: In conclusion, $\langle{Tu,v\rangle}=0$ for all $v,u\in X$. Choose $v=Tu$ to get $0=||Tu||^2$.

Comment: Do we need continuity of $T$ here?

Comment: @MeetPatel No. the reason for the stipulation of boundedness is that this exercise from a part of the textbook that has yet to discuss unbounded operators.