# Let $X$ a complex inner product space and $T, S\in B(X)$. $T\equiv S$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\langle Tx,x\rangle=\langle Sx,x \rangle, \forall x\in X$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

($\Rightarrow$) This implication is immediate (is valid for real spaces).

($\Leftarrow$) (is not valid for real spaces) Suppose $\langle Tx,x \rangle=\langle Sx,x \rangle$ for all $x\in X$. And i dont know what to do

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I think I'm making a mistake in the calculations. Im find $\langle x, Tx\rangle=\langle x, Sx\rangle.$ ='(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\langle Tx,x \rangle=\langle Sx,x \rangle$ for all $x\in X$. Hence $$ \langle (T-S)x,x \rangle=0, \forall x\in X.$$ How to $X$ is a complex IPS we had $(T-S)\equiv 0$. Because, if $\langle Tz,z \rangle=0$ for all $z\in X$, then $T\equiv 0$ how to showing in [Prove that if $\langle Tx,x\rangle =0$ for all $x \in X$, then $T = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307747/prove-that-if-langle-tx-x-rangle-0-for-all-x-in-x-then-t-0).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $$T(x,y)=(-y,x)$$
$$S(x,y) =(-2y,2x)$$ then $$\left<T(x,y),(x,y)\right>=-yx+xy =0$$
$$\left<S(x,y) ,(x,y)\right>=-2yx +2xy=0$$
hence $$\left<T(x,y) ,(x,y)\right>=\left<S(x,y),(x,y)\right>$$
for $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 $ but $$S\neq T.$$

Comment: Neither your $S$ nor your $T$ appear to be bounded, so how does this answer the question?