# Let $T\in B(H)$ be such that $\langle Tx,x \rangle = 0$ for all $x\in H$. Prove that $T=0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space. Let $T\in B(H)$ be such that $\langle T x,x\rangle = 0$ for all $x\in H$. Prove that $T=0$. Here $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product, and $B(H)$ is the space of bounded linear operators.

How do I show $T$ that is the $0$ operator?
I thought of considering $x=au+bv$ in $H$ and then $$T(x)=T(au+bv)=aT(u)+bT(v)$$

Hints would be great.

Comment: is equal to $0$

Comment: The result is true only if $H$ is a *complex* Hilbert space. Otherwise a rotation by $90^o$ in $\Bbb R^2$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307747/prove-that-if-langle-tx-x-rangle-0-for-all-x-in-x-then-t-0?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that $\langle Tx, y \rangle = 0$ for all $x,y \in H$ implies $T=0$.

Consider
$$
\begin{aligned}
0 &= \langle T(\alpha x + y), \alpha x + y\rangle  \\
&= |\alpha|^2 \langle Tx, x\rangle + \alpha \langle T x, y \rangle + \alpha^* \langle T y, x \rangle + \langle T y, y \rangle \\
&= \alpha \langle T x, y\rangle + \alpha^* \langle T y, x \rangle,
\end{aligned}
$$
which holds for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. Now together the cases $\alpha = 1$ and $\alpha = i$ imply that $\langle T x, y \rangle = 0$ for all $x,y \in H$.

Note that we require the Hilbert space to be over $\mathbb{C}$ for this to hold however. For a counterexample consider the Hilbert space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard Euclidean inner product and take
$$
T = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then for $x = (x_1,x_2)$ we have $Tx = (-x_2,x_1)$ and so $\langle Tx, x \rangle = -x_2 x_1 + x_1 x_2 = 0$ but $T \neq 0$.

Comment: what is $\alpha^*$ here?

Comment: @ShanOH Complex conjugate of $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you. This explains well